# Marshaling C++ int* to C#

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I am trying to get a dll to work.

The DLL is written in C++, and it needs to pass int* to C#. I spent passed few days to get this to work, and it fails. I am starting to pull my hair out because I can not figure out what is wrong. I have tried everything. I am not as familiar with C++ as I am with C#, so problem might be coming from there...

It reads fine from the dll, but the values returned are not correct. I removed the inputs, and I am just trying to get a test array through. The function I am using in C++ is:

```
extern "C" EAGLE128DLL_API int* encryptFunc()
{
    //return encrypt(x, Q);

    int t[128];

    for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {
        t[i] = 5;
    }

    return t;
};
```

The C# code I use to call this function is as follows:

```
[DllImport("C:\\Users\\Leon\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Eagle128DLL\\Release\\Eagle128DLL.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr encryptFunc();
    ...

IntPtr outputPtr = encryptFunc();
int[] output = new int[128];

Marshal.Copy(outputPtr, output, 0, 128);
```

The values within output array should be all 5's. But what i get is: 
16187392, 16190224..etc (not 5's)

Comment: You should also be able to use the [return: MarshalAs] attribute to return an int[] rather than an IntPtr and let the marshaller do the work for you: [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 128)] public static extern int[] encryptFunc();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ code contains an error: you are returning a pointer to a variable stored on the stack (`t[128]` is only a temporary variable), which will not work. As soon as your `encryptFunc` returns, the [call stack will be unwound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) and the variable `t[128]` will be trashed.

If your code needs not be re-entrant or thread safe, you can simply make `t[128]` static:

```
static int t[128];
...
return t;
```

A static variable will no longer be stored on the stack and will survive the end of the function.

Comment: haha cant believe it was that simple. The biggest hair pullers are always oh so simple that one would not even think about it...Thank you so much!!

Comment: I am guessing I should use a delete[] on static arrays to remove them from memory once done with them?

Comment: No, don't do that. Only use delete[] on memory that has been allocated on the heap (using new). There should not be any need for you to delete static variables.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is that you are trying to return a value that has been declared locally on the stack in your C function.

The best thing is to pass in a preallocated array to your C function which will receive the data that the function creates and return it back to the caller.